# What is the difference between typedef and enum

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

I am trying to use typedef and enum. I have got two lines.Is there any difference between two following lines ?

```
typedef enum {UNDEFINED, POINT2D, POINT3D, CIRCLE, SQUARE, RECTANGLE, SPHERE} STYPE

enum STYPE {UNDEFINED, POINT2D, POINT3D, CIRCLE, SQUARE, RECTANGLE, SPHERE}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First line defines an `enum` with no tag, and gives it a name `STYPE`
- Second line defines a named `enum` called `STYPE`

The difference is that the first `enum` does not have an enum tag, while the second one does. In other words, both lines below will compile for `enum STYPE`

```
STYPE s1;
enum STYPE s2;
```

while only the first line will compile for the `typedef enum ... STYPE`.

**Note:** Using `typedef` is not common in C++, because `enum` defines a type name automatically. The construct is more common in C, where `enum` without `typedef` must be used only as a tag, i.e. with `enum` keyword. Finally, this construct is also used in C:

```
typedef enum STYPE {UNDEFINED, POINT2D, POINT3D, CIRCLE, SQUARE, RECTANGLE, SPHERE} STYPE;
```

It defines a tagged `enum`, and defines a type name for it. This declaration is also allowed in C++, but it is not different from your second declaration.